# Basic Authentication with core-ajax Polymer elements

Tags: polymer, basic-authentication

did anyone try to retrieve data from URL with Basic Authentication, using the core-ajax element in Polymer?

this is the standard element I'm using:

```
<core-ajax id="ajax"
                   auto
                   url="hereIputmyURL"
                   handleAs="json"
                   method="GET"
                   on-core-response="{{postsLoaded}}"
                   >
    </core-ajax>
```

and I found here (http://un.codiert.org/2014/09/polymer-core-ajax-basic-authorization/) that I need to add this JS

> this.$.ajax.headers='{"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"'
>                 + ', "Authorization": "Basic ' 
>                 + btoa(this.username + ":" + this.password) + '"}';

I'm not sure where exactly I have to add the JS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would look like this...

```html
<template>
  <core-ajax id="ajax" auto url="hereIputmyURL" 
             handleAs="json" method="GET" 
             on-core-response="{{postsLoaded}}">
  </core-ajax>
  <div>
    <content></content>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  Polymer({
    ready: function(){
       this.$.ajax.headers = '{"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"' + 
                          ', "Authorization": "Basic ' + btoa(this.username 
                          + ":" + this.password) + '"}';
       });
    }
</script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: Yes, I already tried but I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined`. For the moment I'm writing the header field I need for auth in the "header" option of the <core-ajax> tag, but it wouldn't allow me to change dinamically username and passw...

Comment: It would be helpful to see your code.  Could you paste it here or may be use ele.io?

Comment: I've updated the code snippet. this was my mistake. The updated block shows the modification is being done the ready callback.

Comment: Thanks, now it works and it's more elegant than my solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "headers" attribute for ajax-core?
Like this:

```
    <core-ajax id="ajax"
                   auto
                   url="hereIputmyURL"
                   handleAs="json"
                   method="GET"
                   on-core-response="{{postsLoaded}}"
                   headers = '{"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"}'
                   >
    </core-ajax>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this worked for me. Just found calling a js variable worked.

```
<core-ajax
    url="http://some.url"
    handleAs="json"
    method="post"
    on-core-response="{{getDetails}}"
    headers="{{headers}}"></core-ajax>



Polymer('element_name', {
    username: 'usernmae',
    password: 'password',
    headers: '{"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"' + ', "Authorization": "Basic ' + btoa(this.username + ":" + this.password) + '"}',
```